# android: Can method Split return a null value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I get a problem when reading this code.

Why does the coder determine that `allProvinces = null`?

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(response)){
    String [] allProvinces = response.split(",");
    /* how should I check whether allProvinces is null or not? 
     * it means the method "split" can possibly return a null value?
     */
    if( allProvinces != null && allProvinces.length > 0){    
        for(String p :allProvinces) {
            String [] array = p.split("//|");
            Province province = new Province();
            province.setProvinceName(array [0]);
            province.setProvinceCode(array[1]);
            weatherDb.saveProvince(province);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can method Split return a null value?

split function always return `String[]` containing at least one element.

You get an array of size 1 holding the original value:

split method with character  **"-"**

```
Input          Output
-----          ------
ABCD-XYZ      {"ABCD", "XYZ"}
QWERT         {"QWERT"}
ZXC-q-        {"ZXC","q"}
ZXC-q- -      {"ZXC","q",""}
```

> why the coder determine **allProvinces =null**

It's useless to check `null` because 
split function always return `String[]` containing at least one element.

Comment: thanks,  can I conclude from your answer that  "if( allProvinces != null && allProvinces.length > 0) {}  " can be removed?

Comment: Welcome @SamuelChan . Yes you can

Answer (score 2):

Code `if( allProvinces != null && allProvinces.length > 0){`  is check allProvinces  not equal to null. 
String split minimum value is one. We can't return split null string.

Comment: I know what you mean, but my question is how can "split " return a null String array? If can't, why should I determine its value

Comment: No need return null string. Because you are checking null or not. You can add `else` statement for return null value.

Comment: it is very kind of you to slove my problem. Cheers!